# How Can i validate age on date field using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, date, validation

I am trying to vallidate age on date input field,  if somone age in 18+ then he can vallid if he isn’t a 18+ from field will be error how can i do that?

Comment: On the callbackf unction invoked on submitting form check age and return something like `{error:"age must be 18 years"}` and and show the error on the screen . I guess

Answer (score 1):

The following copies a given birthdate into a new constant `b18` and varies it by adding 18 years to it. The comparison with the current date then shows whether the person is 18 years old or not.

```js
// const b contains birth date to be tested
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input",function(){

 const b=new Date(this.value);

 const b18=new Date(b.getTime());
 b18.setYear(b.getFullYear()+18);

 // alternatively you could calculate that "critical birthdate", 
 // 18 years ago, that makes you an adult today:
 const d18=new Date();
 d18.setYear(d18.getFullYear()-18);

 console.log(new Date()>b18,d18>b);
})
```

```html
<input type ="date" value="2003-08-29">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
        <input id="age" type="number" />
```

```
        let age = document.getElementById('age');
        let minAge = 18;

        age.onchange = () => {
            if(!age.value >= minAge){
                    age.style.border = "1px solid red";
                } else if(age.value >= minAge) {
                    ​age.style.border = "1px solid green";
                }
        }
 ​
```